# Design Pattern for Infinite Loop + threaded services/interfaces?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, queue, embedded-linux, infinite-loop

For almost 20y. of Embedded/C++ dev., I often fall back into the same situation of an infinite loop populated with different threaded services Class (start/stopped through Abstract Factory/Singleton design patterns) like TCP Socket, CAN bus, Serial link, logging, power, FDIR, data-pool, Telemetry/Telecomand Engine (Command parser design pattern), all these services being interfaced through RX/TX queues. 
This leads often to Service-Interface class being instantiated (once, singleton of-course) globaly (don't scream!) and/or having the infinite loop relying on a C/Glib g_main_loop() (don't yell!)

While I often read this kind of architecture being referred as producer/worker/client, I kind of have a hard time finding an appropriate design pattern to follow as a best practice or code reference/skeleton for such an architecture.

I am probably missing the appropriate vocabulary (I am 90% C++ autodidact) and/or the good starting point...

As StackOverflow bans fuzzy questions, I guess my issue could be reduced at understanding what should be (or not!) in the main() function (e.g. where/when to construct/start/stop interface classes) and/or what is a good reference code to read/refer for a multi-threaded/queued-services around an infinite while() loop in modern C++ ?

So indeed rather a philosophical question here, I hope I could describe it in a clear manner...if not, please help me to rephrase it appropriately.

Thank you,

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: This is a good question, but I'd rather see it suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. You can further improve it by spending some time on research (which similar Q/As already exist over there), formatting (method names as code etc.) and spelling, which will improve your chances it's well received.